# How do I loop date picker with weekly data YTD

Tags: python, selenium

I am interested in downloading the weekly data YTD from Sunday to Saturday. Right now, I am sending keys to the date picker to get the date range. But I want a loop to download the file on a weekly aggregate.

```
# Get datatime
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-component/app-navigation/div/app-campaign/app-campaign-list-dashboard/div/div/app-filter-bar/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/app-time-period-selector/div/div[1]/input").send_keys('24/07/2022 - 30/07/2022')
time.sleep(3)

# Download Report 

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/app-component/app-navigation/div/app-campaign/app-campaign-list-dashboard/div/div/div[5]/cc-report-table-container/div/div[3]/div[2]/cc-drop-up-button/div/div/button").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-component/app-navigation/div/app-campaign/app-campaign-list-dashboard/div/div/div[5]/cc-report-table-container/div/div[3]/div[2]/cc-drop-up-button/div/div/ul/li[2]/a").click()
#/html/body/app-component/app-navigation/div/app-campaign/app-campaign-list-dashboard/div/div/div[5]/cc-report-table-container/div/div[3]/div[2]/cc-drop-up-button/div/div/ul/li[1]/a
```

Comment: can you share the page url please @Mustard

Comment: It's a gated website so. Is there anyway to do that to replace what is in 
 send_keys?